# Size Agnostic UICollectionView//UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I am trying to figure out if there's a way to create something like a UICollectionView for an arbitrary and potentially infinite amount of UICollectionViewCells.  I also want to be able to do fancy things with my own UICollectionViewLayout.

What I'm trying to do is create a dataSource that's a linked-list.  So each element in the dataSource knows which element comes before and after it.  I have no idea how big the list is.  I don't care.

I've looked at the UITableView stuff and it needs to know how many elements are in it.  I've looked at the UICollectionView stuff and it ALSO needs to know how many elements are in it.   The UICollectionViewLayout needs to know how big the view needs to be (collectionViewContentSize).  All of this is frustrating to me because I don't see why this much detail is needed.

For simplicities sake, lets assume that I only need to show ONE cell at a time.  I don't see why I can't just tell the View that it's only 3-cells wide (always) and when you scroll to the left or right, pop the cell of the long side and put it on the short side?  At no point will I need to be able to say "scroll to 5" I just want to be able to say "next, next, next" or "prev, prev, prev"

What's the best way to capture this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

The best answer I can think of thus far is to basically do what I said w/ the "use three cells" thing.  I could just have a CollectionView that is concerned with how to best lay out some n-cells (where n is 3, or 5, or 25, or somethign) and some other thing that is concerned with what to be putting in each cell and while the view is cycling between the same n cells, the data thing is pushing the appropriate data into them?